# Got the error message of "Got invalid HTTP method: expecting only POST"

Tags: kaa

We use the Kaa version 0.9 and got a error message like below. But, we just send log to Kaa server from endpoint at that time. The log we sent is normal data. Have anyone can give us some suggestion about this error message, thanks.

```
2016-11-09 16:53:46,104 [nioEventLoopGroup-9-3] ERROR o.k.k.s.t.h.t.netty.RequestDecoder - Got invalid HTTP method: expecting only POST
2016-11-09 16:53:46,104 [nioEventLoopGroup-9-3] ERROR o.k.k.s.t.h.t.n.DefaultExceptionHandler - Exception caught
org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common.server.BadRequestException: Incorrect method GET, expected POST
at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.transports.http.transport.netty.RequestDecoder.channelRead0(RequestDecoder.java:75) ~[transport-0.9.0-http.jar:na]
at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.transports.http.transport.netty.RequestDecoder.channelRead0(RequestDecoder.java:43) ~[transport-0.9.0-http.jar:na]
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) ~[netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:293) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) [netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:293) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) [netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:263) [netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:293) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:840) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354) [netty-transport-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112) [netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137) [netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about this issue? What actions did you perform that lead to this exception? Did you use demo application from Sandbox or it's your own application? Provide full client application and Kaa server logs with TRACE log level for detailed investigation. Use [troubleshooting](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Administration-guide/Troubleshooting/) guide for details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is our own application. In our application, we just use send notification to endpoints and send log from endpoint to Kaa server and the log appender is Kafka. We set server logs with TRACE  all day and the server log have no this error message this time. We will keep to trace it.